# Permanent redirection with "sub-routes"

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I need to change the base of the routing system in my Sf2 project.

I used the `FrameworkBundle:Redirect:urlRedirect` to redirect permanently few routes, like this :

```
# File : app/config/routing.yml
# ..
redirect_route_example:
    pattern: /foo
   defaults:
       _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:urlRedirect
       path: /
       permanent: true
# ..
```

If I have a lot of subroutes with my "master route" `/foo`
(like `/foo/page1`, `/foo/page2`, `/foo/page1/subpage1`, etc.)

Is it possible to make the same thing with my `FrameworkBundle:Redirect:urlRedirect` but with a regex route (like `/foo/*` -> `/*`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My thought was to just add a parameter right after the `/foo`, like `/foo{subroutes}` and to allow slashes in this parameter. So we basically need this:

http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/routing/slash_in_parameter.html

The solution then could look something like this:

```
# File : app/config/routing.yml
# ..
redirect_route_example:
    path: /foo{subroutes}
    requirements:
        subroutes: ".*"
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:urlRedirect
        path: /
        permanent: true
# ..
```

**EDIT:**

Note that this solution redirects everything to `/` that starts with `/foo` which probably isn't the behaviour you want. If you want to keep the subroute itself and only get rid of the `/foo` at the beginning, use the key `route` instead of `path` and the controller `FrameworkBundle:Redirect:redirect` instead of `urlRedirect` in the `defaults` of the `redirect_routing_sample` and use a route with the parameter `{subroutes}`.